# find formula based on the truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

i was given this truth table and i had to find the formula for it. I am basically stuck:

```
A   B   C   ?
T   T   T   F
T   T   F   T
T   F   T   F
T   F   F   F
F   T   T   F
F   T   F   T
F   F   T   F
F   F   F   T
```

i came up with this, but it is not correct

```
(A∧B∧C) ∨ (A∧B∧¬C) ∨ (A∧¬B∧C) ∨
(A∧¬B∧¬C) ∨ (¬A∧B∧¬C) ∨ (¬A∧¬B∧C) ∨
(¬A∧¬B∧¬C)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you really wanted to do this the long way like it looks like your attempt wanted to... then yes, you could use building blocks like $A\wedge B\wedge C$ or $\neg A\wedge B\wedge \neg C$ and so on, and `or`'ing them together... but if you do decide to do it that way then you should **only** include those whose final column was true and *not* include any whose final column was false.

Comment: As an aside... in your attempt it almost looks like you tried to use *every* triple possible, but but somehow you used seven of them and not all eight.  Your expression you came up with was for the truth table whose final column was true in every case except for the fifth row, corresponding to the missing $\neg A\wedge B\wedge C$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The" formula is not unique but here is a short one:$$\neg C\land(B\lor\neg A)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just focus on the rows where the mystery statement is True.

For example, the statement is true in row 2, which is where $A$ and $B$ are True, but $C$ is False.  So that row corresponds to the term $A \land B \land \neg C$.

Generate terms like that for all rows where the statement is true, and disjunct (or) them all together. In your case, that gives you:

$$(A \land B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg A \land \neg B \land \neg C)$$

This can be simplified, but it's a good start. Like I said: just focus on the rows where the expression is True.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> A B   C   ?
> T T   T   F
> T T   F   T
> T F   T   F
> T F   F   F
> F T   T   F
> F T   F   T
> F F   T   F
> F F   F   T
> ```

> I came up with this, but it is not correct:

> ```
> (A∧B∧C) ∨ (A∧B∧¬C) ∨ (A∧¬B∧C) ∨
> (A∧¬B∧¬C) ∨ (¬A∧B∧¬C) ∨ (¬A∧¬B∧C) ∨
> (¬A∧¬B∧¬C)
> ```

Should be:

```
¬(A∧B∧C) ∨ 
 (A∧B∧¬C) ∨ 
¬(A∧¬B∧C) ∨
¬(A∧¬B∧¬C) ∨ 
¬(¬A∧B∧C) ∨
 (¬A∧B∧¬C) ∨
¬(¬A∧¬B∧C) ∨
 (¬A∧¬B∧¬C)
```

This could, of course, be simplified.